# Cron Job issue Magento

Tags: magento

the issue I am facing is that order emails not working on my magento store. I installed AOE scheduler but I am getting this issue

***No heartbeat task found. Check if cron is configured correctly.***

Though I have set the settings on cpanel
[image]

and AOE scheduler settings on magento
[image]

I am getting this email every second

```
Available actions: 
    --action listAllCodes
    --action lastRun --code <code> [--secondsFromNow]   Get the timestamp of the last successful run of a job for a given code
    --action scheduleNow --code <code>  Schedule a job to be executed as soon as possible
    --action runNow --code <code> [--tryLock] [--force]         Run a job directly
    --action wait [--timout <timeout=60>]               Active wait until no schedules are running.
    --action flushSchedules --mode (future|all)         Flush schedules.
    --action listAllRunningSchedules
    --action killAll
    --action watchdog
    --action cron --mode (always|default) [--includeJobs <comma separated list of jobs>] [--excludeJobs <comma separated list of jobs>] [--includeGroups <comma separated list of groups>] [--excludeGroups <comma separated list of groups>]
```

I am stuck I dont know how to resolve this issue, please help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/186044/cron-jobs-for-order-emails?noredirect=1#comment257244_186044

Looks like PATH variable is set somehow different in jailshelled cron environment. So I suppose different php binary is used. You can ssh to your cPanel account and set PATH in your crontab.

So crontab should start like:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/cpanel/composer/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/home/username/.local/bin:/home/username/bin
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is something that is hidden in the Magento 2 documentation. Once you install Magento 2 with composer you are not done installing. One needs to go under the /update/ folder and run `composer update` again so it installs some needed packages for the cron to work properly.

I've seen many Magento2 setups where this extra step was not done, hence everything works except the cron.

If you use command line, it should look like this:

```
[html]$ cd update/
[update]$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 29 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing psr/log (1.0.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing monolog/monolog (1.16.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/yaml (v2.8.25): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/version (1.0.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/recursion-context (1.0.5): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/exporter (1.2.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/environment (1.3.8): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/diff (1.4.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/comparator (1.2.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/instantiator (1.0.5): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/php-text-template (1.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects (2.3.8): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/php-timer (1.0.9): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/php-file-iterator (1.3.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/php-token-stream (1.4.11): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/php-code-coverage (2.2.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/phpunit (4.1.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/console (v2.6.13): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/process (v3.3.5): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/finder (v3.3.5): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/filesystem (v3.3.5): Loading from cache
  - Installing seld/phar-utils (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing seld/jsonlint (1.6.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing seld/cli-prompt (1.0.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing justinrainbow/json-schema (1.6.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing composer/spdx-licenses (1.1.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing composer/semver (1.4.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing composer/composer (1.0.0-beta1): Loading from cache
  - Installing magento/composer (1.0.3): Loading from cache
monolog/monolog suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Allow sending log messages to AWS services like DynamoDB)
monolog/monolog suggests installing doctrine/couchdb (Allow sending log messages to a CouchDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-mongo (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing graylog2/gelf-php (Allow sending log messages to a GrayLog2 server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing php-console/php-console (Allow sending log messages to Google Chrome)
monolog/monolog suggests installing raven/raven (Allow sending log messages to a Sentry server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing rollbar/rollbar (Allow sending log messages to Rollbar)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ruflin/elastica (Allow sending log messages to an Elastic Search server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing videlalvaro/php-amqplib (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server using php-amqplib)
phpunit/phpunit suggests installing phpunit/php-invoker (~1.1)
symfony/console suggests installing symfony/event-dispatcher ()
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
[update]$
```

Comment: I am not using magento 2

Comment: In Magento 1 - most cron issues are related to file permissions OR something is terribly wrong with one of your modules so it crashes the cron mid-way.